# How to fix this heavy shelving unit to solid supporting wall?

Tags: walls

[image][image]

[image]

Can someone please advise on the best fixings to use. I want this shelving unit to be hung to a solid brick wall like a kitchen cupboard. It weighs approximately 20kg. The back is longer than under the draws so difficult to fit a bracket at the bottom.

Comment: I think the two metal brackets at the top wouldn't hold the weight of the unit on the wall. There is going to be nothing underneath this unit.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I have been clear. I want it to be off the floor attached to the wall, like a kitchen cupboard.

Comment: please edit your post to make it clear

Comment: a picture of the side that touches the wall would be way more useful

Answer (score 1):

A Z bar hanger may work well. The lower half is fixed to the wall; the upper half is fixed to the object. Caveat: walls are sometimes not a flat plane, but instead have some curve to them. Use a straight edge to confirm your wall is flat where the mounting bar would go. If it isn't then it can be corrected by inserting shims behind the bar. (image credit: http://www.zbarhanger.com)

[image]

The bar will carry the weight of the cabinet with no trouble but it may be a good idea to use a few more fasteners directly through the cabinet into the wall, especially in the lower part of the cabinet. These would prevent the bottom of the cabinet being lifted away from the wall, the cabinet being slid sideways, or the cabinet being bumped upward enough to disengage the mounting bar.

Comment: Looks like a metal version of a [french cleat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_cleat)